# What variables are in the scope of an image .onerror call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onerror

I've got the following function in a project I'm working on:

```
var makePreviewSimulationDiv = function(){
    var errorFlag = false;

    imgError = function(image){
        errorFlag = true;
    };

    var that = this, proxy = new IAProxy(),
        //imageSource = real_image_source,
        imageSource = "",
        image = that.append('<img class="foo" onerror="imgError(this);
                            "src=' + imageSource + '></img>')
                    .children('.sim-ui-preview-sim-image'),
        container = image.run(encapsulateImg),
        iconsDiv = that.append('<div class="bar"></div>')
                       .children('.bar');

    if (!errorFlag){
        image.load(function(){
            container.run(zoomMaxWidth)
                .run(makeDraggable)
                .run(makeZoomable);
        });
    } else{
        alert('image load error!');
    }

    return that;
};
```

Currently, I have the image src set to `""` to try to debug the behavior of the function if it gets a bad image src or no image src in an effort to make it fail gracefully. Currently, my code is correctly catching the error and throwing `alert('image load error!');`. However, if I locally scope my `imgError` function, i.e. change the code to the following:

```
    var imgError = function(image){
        errorFlag = true;
    };
```

`imgError` can no longer be found when `onerror` triggers on the image load. What is the scope of the function called in `onerror`, and can I move `imgError` into it's scope without declaring it globally  and while still being able to access `errorFlag` from within `imgError`?

Comment: In your case, just the image itself and the window.

Comment: Is there a way of restructuring how I'm adding the .onerror attribute to the image that would allow me to access local variables of the makePreviewSimulationDiv function?

Comment: Yes, create the image with `var img = new Image()`, bind to it's error and load handlers and set it's src with `$(img).on("load",loadHandler").on("error",errorHandler)[0].src = imageSource`. Now, inside of both of aformentioned handlers, you have access to `this` and the first argument of said handlers will be the event object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create the image with

```
var img = new Image()
```

bind to it's error and load handlers and set it's src with

```
$(img).on("load",loadHandler).on("error",errorHandler)[0].src = imageSource;
```

Now, inside of both of aforementioned handlers, you have access to `this` and the first argument of said handlers will be the `event object`.

```
function errorHandler(event) {
    console.log(event);
}
function loadHandler(event) {
    console.log(event);
    $(this).appendTo("#imgHolder");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with the help of Kevin B's comment. This was my solution:

```
var makePreviewSimulationDiv = function(){
    var errorFlag = false;

    var that = this, proxy = new IAProxy(),
        image = that.append('<img class="foo"></img>').children('.foo'),
        imageSource = ""; //a source that should cause an error


    var imgError = function(image){
        errorFlag = true;
    };

    image.on("error",imgError)[0].src = imageSource

    var container = image.run(encapsulateImg),
        iconsDiv = that.append('<div class="bar"></div>').children('.bar');

    if (!errorFlag){
        image.load(function(){
            container.run(zoomMaxWidth)
                .run(makeDraggable)
                .run(makeZoomable);
        });
    } else{
        alert('image load error!');
    }

    return that;
};
```

Comment: Ah yes, now I understand the question! The original way you were appending the function, it would only be looking for `onerror="imgError(this)"` <-- **imgError** being a global function / variable, that's why it wasn't working.